# How can i zoom mask uiimage?

Tags: scroll, uiimage, swift4, masking

[mask remove after zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfQeE.png)[mask image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNjMm.png)I want to zoom the masked image.

I can display the mask image but when i try to zoom the image then mask is not working.
I want to zoom the image in mask area only.

Comment: Please provide the code which you are using

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code below. its working for me.

```swift
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrolView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgPhoto: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrolView.delegate = self
        scrolView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrolView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0
    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imgPhoto
    }
}
```

Comment: viewForZooming return UIView and you are returning UIImageView ?? Is it fine ??